# Aspose.Cells vs SmartXLS

Tags: c#, .net, excel, smartxls

Has anybody used/evaluated both of these libraries and can tell me the difference?
Otherwise has anyone here used SmartXLS for reading/creating/updating excel files and can tell me his experience?
The later is considerably cheaper than the former.

Answer (score 2):

I have used SmartXLS for quite some projects for my clients and it works fine for me. I use it to create Excel files from scratch, but also to update existing Excel files (XML, XLS and XLSX). I only have textual information in my sheets. No formulas, images, etc.
In the past, I have encountered a bug once. The SmartXLS team fixed it within one hour after I reported it. Recently, for another project I needed an extension to their library (save as XML). Even despite the fact that I do not have a support contract, they implemented it for me within two days. I wanted to share that they have good customer support, which is for me one of the most important aspects when I purchase a 3rd party library. Disclaimer: I do not work for SmartXLS and am not sponsored.

Comment: Can you reuse a workbook in smartxls? For example, to change input and do recalculate?

Answer (score 1):

I have used SmartXLS is several projects to create spreadsheets from scratch, or to use one as template. Sofar everything I wanted it to do, it did. Disclaimer, I neither work for or am sponsored by SmartXLS' developers.

Comment: and where is the link for SmartXLS ?

Comment: google.com?q=smartxls